# ffmpeg clear video cache

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, compression

I am running a compression script to compress my large AVI files to small mp4 files. The script look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FILEPATH="$1"
COMPRESSIONPATH="$2"

ffmpeg -i $FILEPATH -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 $COMPRESSIONPATH
sudo rm $FILEPATH
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X GET "http://localhost:3000/clovis/api/led"
```

Whenever I save a compressed video with a filename of `compressedVideo#0.mp4` and open it; the newly compressed mp4 file contains footage of a very old video that I recorded and deleted about a week ago. It's almost as `ffmpeg` is cache that delete video and compressing any filename with `compressVideo#0.mp4` with the cached video. What might be the case here? How do I clear `ffmpeg` cache? Changing the filename fixes this issue, but I wanted to use the filename `compressedVideo#0.mp4`. There are a few filenames that won't work actually; `compressedVideo#0-4.mp4` all won't work. Depending on the filename used it loads the corresponding video that was created and delete long ago.

Answer (score 3):

Solved by clearing browser cache.

Comment: Sure? What's the relation between a bash script using ffmpeg with your browser? What if I have a lot of different browsers installed? Which one should its cache be cleared?